# Question on Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers and FxCop analyzers

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

in my .net project(Target Framework 4.7), in code analysis tab, I see **Run on build** was checked.  so am able to see some FxCop warnings.  but when I checked  nuGet packages, I see that Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers is not installed.  so my first question is when FxCopAnalyzers nuget package is not installed, how are the warnings showing up?

Moving now, when I upgraded to VS2019, I get below error

```
Warning CA0507 Post-build Code Analysis (FxCopCmd.exe) has been deprecated in favor of FxCop analyzers
```

so I googled and found that FxCopAnalyzers are no longer supported and are replaced with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.

I did the steps mentioned here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers

1. installed the package
2. did this to the project file by editing it in notepad.

   [image]

the Warning CA050 is gone now, but I don't get any warnings that was coming before.  I was expecting Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers to generate the same set of warning that was coming before(even thouugh i dont know how it was coming).  What am I missing?  am not sure if Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers is even doing its job.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/migrate-from-fxcop-analyzers-to-net-analyzers?view=vs-2019)?

Answer (score 2):

I have too little reputation to comment. I recommend reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/net-analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019

TLDR: FxCop when used as a Roslyn analyzer is not the same analyzer as FxCop in Visual Studio (legacy FxCop). Some rules from legacy FxCop are *not* present in newer FxCop.

For a list of rules that have not been ported, see below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-unported-rules-may-get-ported?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-unported-deprecated-rules?view=vs-2019